# Effect on existing images after changing JPEG quality (GD toolkit) in Drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

On our Drupal 7 website with thousands of images, JPEG quality in GD toolkit was set at 100%.

This caused well-optimized images to be 150-200% larger if 'image styles' were used instead of 'original images'. But we need to use styles to keep images ratio consistent. CSS 'object-fit' is not an option for cross-browser reasons.

What will happen to the quality of existing images if we reduce quality to 60%?

**Update**: As far as I tested it should not have any effect on the existing images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(New) image style image (thumbnail) is generated if old one is not found. There is no point of re-generating thumbnails every time they are displayed since it would required too much server/resources.

If you want some thumbnail regenerated it should be enough to just delete thumbnail file. Next time it's called it will be generated again.

There is also a module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagestyleflush

Check on this thread to see other options:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/rebuild-images-from-image-style